# Drop Down box with Ajax in Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Can any one suggest me how to do Ajax in Jquery

here i am having code like a drop box with  b.tech b.sc , if i click on the b.tech second drop down box should activate and it should contain eee ece it like that. Can any one suggest me the code

here is HTML code

```
  <select id="coursename" name="coursename" onchange="loadSpec(this.value)" >  
         <option value="-1">Select One</option> 
         <option value="1">B.Sc</option>
         <option value="2">B.Com</option>
         <option value="3">B.Tech</option>
    </select>


   <select id="specialized" name="specialized" ></select>
</body>
</html>
```

please suggest me...........

Comment: What does `loadSpec` do?

Comment: How are you going to load specialization data? From server or from local variable? and what dies this `loadSpec()` function do?
The code you have shown is too less to help you in particular.

Comment: I see your similar question was `closed` for not being descriptive enough... This will be closed too...

Comment: sorry to miss that, previously i have a code with core ajax.... now i want to change code there i mean loadSpec() only.....can any one suggest the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
<select id="coursename" name="coursename" onchange="loadSpec()">  
     <option value="-1">Select One</option> 
     <option value="1">B.Sc</option>
     <option value="2">B.Com</option>
     <option value="3">B.Tech</option>
</select>
<div id="div1">
   <select id="1" name="coursename" style="display:none;">  
     <option value="-1">Select One</option> 
     <option value="1">aaa</option>
     <option value="2">bbb</option>
     <option value="3">ccc</option>
</select>
   <select id="2" name="coursename" style="display:none;">  
     <option value="-1">Select One</option> 
     <option value="1">ddd</option>
     <option value="2">eee</option>
     <option value="3">fff</option>
</select>
</div>
```

and script is like this

```
function loadSpec() {
     var val = $('#coursename').val();
     $('#coursename').val();
     $('#div1 select').hide();
     $('#' + val + '').css('display', 'block');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for solution but this is normal jquery but i want a code with Ajax , if you don't mine could you please explain that

Comment: options of B.com, B.Tech are in database or they are fixed?

Comment: those are just fixed things ,i am not connecting with any database

Answer (score 0):

Try using knockout JS. It is used to make dynamic websites using ajax, jquery and HTML.

```
http://knockoutjs.com/
```

The website is well documented and you can find examples all over the internet. Hope it helps you